# Сортировка дат

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Добрый день.
Есть таблица вида

```
|id| activ | dateTime |
------------------------------
|1 | no-activ | 2012-01-13 01:06:50 |
|2 | activ   | 2012-01-13 01:06:50 |
|3 | activ | 2012-01-13 01:06:50 |
|4 | no-activ | 2012-01-13 01:07:50 |
```

Сейчас 2012-01-13 01:07:00. Надо отсортировать все записи которые меньше чем сейчас и `activ` = 'activ' и выввести все `id`. Я делаю так:

```
"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `activ` WHERE `dateTime`<LOCALTIME() AND `activ`='activ';"
```

и выводит количество записей, подходящих по параметрам. Но при этом, если я задам вот так запрос:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `activ` WHERE `dateTime`<LOCALTIME() AND `activ`='activ';"
```

то ничего не приисходит. В чем ошибка???

Answer (score 2):

Храните дату в timestamp, по нему и сортируйте

```
int mktime ([int hour [, int minute [, int second [, int month [, int day [, int year [, int is_dst]]]]]]])
```

Получение текущей даты `time()`

Чтоб вернуть обратно в привычный вид используйте `strftime('%d.%m.%Y',дата в timestamp);`

Answer (score 2):

Суля по первой таблице в запросе ошибочно используется несуществующее поле `dateTime`.

Нужно:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `activ` WHERE `date`<LOCALTIME() AND `activ`='activ'
```

И:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `activ` WHERE `date`<LOCALTIME() AND `activ`='activ'
```

Comment: нет поле уменя в таблице dataTime но здесь чтото забыл "Time" приписать.